# Approximating a hitting time for some state using the stationary distribution?

Tags: random-walks, pr.probability, markov-chains

Provided a random walk on a bounded interval, with step probabilities, $p$ and $q$ and a stationary distribution $\pi$, how "bad" of an approximation is to assume that the hitting time for a position $x=j$ is proportional to $\approx \pi(j)^{-1}$?  Can the error be bounded?

Comment: the stationary distribution contains no dynamical information, so I don't see how it could be used to approximate the hitting time.

Answer (score 3):

Let's abstract from the random walk formulation, as you first have to specify what do you mean by the random walk on a bounded interval. In any case, it will be an example of an irreducible finite-state Markov Chain $\Phi$. Let $\pi$ be the invariant *probability* distribution of $\Phi$. We know that for any state $j$:
$$
  \pi(j) = \frac{1}{\mathsf E_j[\tau_j]} \ ,
$$
see e.g. [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s17.pdf), so 
$$
  \mathsf E_j[\tau_j] = \frac{1}{\pi(j)}
$$
and it does make sense to estimate $\tau_j$ as its expected value. The quality of such approximation may be found e.g. using the standard deviation of $\tau_j$. Please, tell me if you are interested in any further details.

Comment: $   C=1        $